# Is there any way to use another server as external storage over the Internet without using the space locally?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, storage, links

I'm working on an Ubuntu 14.04 server with a very good processor and plenty of RAM, yet limited disk quota available (1GB) yet I'd really like to have access to more - I have another Ubuntu 14.04 server available with plenty of disk space but I can't do the work on that as I need the processing power and memory.
My question is whether there's any way to create something similar to a hard link yet from one server to another, meaning that if I were to create a folder "backups", and had the script automatically adding to that folder, all files added to that folder should be uploaded to the other server, yet the script can still delete the files on this server (as usual, rather than using any special commands, I'm not able to change the script).

I wouldn't be surprised if this isn't possible or wouldn't be very easy, but any help would be appreciated! Feel free to comment for more info.

Comment: No reason why not, just don't expect fast access without expensive dedicated lines- I know plenty of people who move files on another server mapped in fstab over an SSH tunnel running on pfsense/mikrotik - you could use rsync to move the files to the remote server.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas my main question is will this be easy to implement without changing the script - I've never worked with any of the things you've mentioned but I'll look into them thanks very much!

Comment: @LukeR I don't think rsync is what you are looking for as it clones files onto the local disk - it does not give you more disk space.  sshfs is, however, entirely practical and something I use most days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 different things here - the problem you are trying to solve (easy) and the question you asked (hard).

**If by "Web" you mean Internet, the problem is easy, and lots of ways of solving it including -**

- Using NFS to remotely mount a directory - this is probably the "standard" way of doing it.
- By using a FUSE filesystem, eg sshfs or ftpfs
- By using SAMBA to provide a "Windows Filesharing" arrangement

  There are also ways you can mount remote block devices, iSCSI as mentioned by @Hongkie being the main one, but really anything which uses "bricks" and abstracts away the filesystem - gluster, moosefs etc - You could even use [nbd](https://nbd.sourceforge.io/) (network block device) - though I would not recommend it.

**The question you actually asked - Using the Web**

This is a lot harder, but doable.  Generally this would use the WebDav protocol which is an extension of HTTP, so something like [dav2fs](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2)

Comment: Apologies, I did indeed mean over the Internet. Informality is a brutal thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on sshfs, could you offer the differences between sshfs and NFS mounting for this?

Comment: This should be a separate question - other then provide file level remote access they are entirely different - ssh is simple and handles encryptiom and done in user space. NFS is done in kernel space so better handles permissions, but is a more complex protocol. I see sshfs as a simple hack for short term use, while NFS as a structured design to share files across a lanor WAN - NFS would require extra security - like a VPN to run it safely over the Internet.

Comment: You should post it as a self-answered question! And ah okay that's great, I should think ssh would be a better option for this, thanks a lot!

Comment: @LukeR This is your question though?

Comment: But davidgo is clearly knowledgeable on the subquestion I asked and he could pose a better question(s) to self answer!

Comment: But David doesn’t have a question.  You are the one with the question.  If you want to ask your other question you should ask it.

Comment: True, possibly.

Comment: @davidgo, I've got a new challenge for you to solve: how can I use sshfs without sudo? Good luck!

Comment: @LukeR sshfs does not require sudo to work - in fact, using sudo probably breaks more then it fixes for sshfs perms. If you need multiuser support NFS is likely more appropriate. If you need need "mapping" from one user to another, the SSH syntax allows you to specify a different username.

Comment: My bad! I was getting these errors:
fusermount: failed to open /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied
fusermount: option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf but removed 'allow_other' and now all appears to be working! Although, it appears to be using disk space on the local server? (As in, when I du -sh the directory, it gives me the size of the contents.)

Comment: Do a "df" to see if its mounted - it should have a line starting x.x.x.x:/path - which will show the usage of the FS as well.   I'm not sure what you would be expecting du to show - of-course its going to show the size of the files its processing - the whole point of doing the mount was to "graft" storage from another system and make it visible as if it were local.

Comment: Ah of course, my apologies, all's working well, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The hard disk link is called **iSCSI**

The end results: in the fast server, There will be a local disk pointing to the slow server. It is a local disk from Ubuntu point of view, regardless physically elsewhere.

For complete setup, here is the link for ubuntu:

http://dalaris.com/how-to-configure-iscsi-target-and-iscsi-initiator-using-ubuntu-14-04-1/

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - it may not be ideal being that it seeks to present as a block device, but its quite a fast, practical solution.